# Why can't a line make obtuse angles with all the three coordinate axes?

Tags: vectors

We were studying vectors and a question was that a line makes same angles with all the three axes,what is the value of direction cosines? The question is why can't a vector or line make an angle of 120° with all the coordinate axes?

Comment: If a line makes an obtuse angle $x^\circ$ with another line, then it also makes an acute angle $(180-x)^\circ$ with that line. So it makes no sense to say that two lines make an obtuse angle. (I am assuming here that at least one of these lines extends to infinity in both directions, which is certainly true of the coordinate axes.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're thinking of rays rather than lines, so that we're looking at the angles between a ray and the positive $x$, $y$, or $z$ axis.

Any ray can be described by a unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}} = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$ with $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}} = 1$ that specifies the direction of the ray. The unit vectors for the positive coordinate axes are of course $\hat{\mathbf{x}}=(1,0,0)$, $\hat{\mathbf{y}}=(0,1,0)$, and $\hat{\mathbf{z}}=(0,0,1)$. The cosine of the angle between two rays is the dot product of their unit vectors. Thus, for our ray with unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, we have $\cos\theta_x = n_x$, $\cos\theta_y = n_y$, and $\cos\theta_z = n_z$. However, from $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}} = 1$ we then get $\cos^2\theta_x + \cos^2\theta_y + \cos^2\theta_z = 1$, which $\theta_x = \theta_y = \theta_z = 120^\circ$ does not satisfy. Therefore no ray can make a $120^\circ$ angle with all three positive coordinate axes.